# Error with custom Page Event Model - Sitecore.XConnect.Schema.XdbModelException

Tags: xconnect, dms

**Environment: Sitecore 9.3**

I have created a custom Page Event.

When I am trying to use it throws this error:

```
48856 14:48:01 ERROR Cannot execute 'sessionEnd:batch:ended' event
Exception: System.AggregateException
Message: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'sessionEnd:batch:ended' event.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Kernel.Web.SessionExpirationProcessor.TryRaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.AggregateException
Message: One or more errors occurred.
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.BatchedXdbContextProxy.SubmitBatch()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.BatchEnabledXdbRuntimeContext.SubmitBatch()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Events.BatchEventHandler.OnBatchEnded(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)

Nested Exception

Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.Schema.XdbModelException
Message: The type of this instance does not correspond to any type in the model. The type is Sitecore93.XConnect.Models.Events.PrintEvent
Source: Sitecore.XConnect.Core
   at Sitecore.XConnect.XdbExtensible.Attach(XdbModel model)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.InteractionOperation.Validate()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.XdbContext.ValidateOperation(IXdbOperation operation)
```

**Following steps taken:**

- Event Model JSON has been deployed to 2 locations: `sc.xconnect\App_Data\Models` and `sc.xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_Data\Models`
- DLL has been deployed to `sc\bin`, `sc.xconnect\bin` and `sc.xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine`
- `Rebuild Indexes`
- `Rebuild Link Databases`
- `Deploy marketing definitions`

**References:**

- https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/en/create-a-custom-event-model.html
- https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/en/convert-a-page-event.html
- https://dogabenli.blogspot.com/2019/02/sitecore-9-custom-page-events-filtering.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you create your  config file for Sitecore? **Deploy the model to core roles** at the end of the page

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/en/deploy-a-custom-model.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
   <sitecore>
      <xconnect>
         <runtime type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.RuntimeModelConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration">
            <schemas hint="list:AddModelConfiguration">
               <!-- value of 'name' property must be unique -->
               <schema name="documentationmodel" type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.StaticModelConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration" patch:after="schema[@name='collectionmodel']">
                  <param desc="modeltype">Documentation.Model.CollectionModel, Documentation.Model</param>
               </schema>
            </schemas>
         </runtime>
      </xconnect>
   </sitecore>
</configuration>
```