# Experience Analytics Data Is Not Coming

Tags: sitecore-client, xconnect

As checked in experience profile, the analytics data is not loading up from last 1-2 months.
Upon checking the xconnect logs we found below exception message:

```
7180 00:00:31 ERROR Cannot execute 'sessionEnd:batch:ended' event
Exception: System.AggregateException Message: One or more exceptions
occurred while processing the subscribers to the
'sessionEnd:batch:ended' event. Source: Sitecore.Kernel    at
Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName,
Object[] parameters, EventResult result)    at
Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[]
parameters)    at
Sitecore.Kernel.Web.SessionExpirationProcessor.TryRaiseEvent(String
eventName, Object[] parameters)

Nested Exception

**Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException**
**Message: {   "Message": "Operation failed: The type initializer for
'AllowedTypesValidatorSerializationBinder' threw an exception." }**
Source: Sitecore.XConnect.Client    at
Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1
taskFactory)    at
Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.BatchedXdbContextProxy.SubmitBatch()
at
Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.BatchEnabledXdbRuntimeContext.SubmitBatch()
at Sitecore.Analytics.Events.BatchEventHandler.OnBatchEnded(Object
sender, EventArgs args)    at
Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName,
Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
```

Earlier we faced issues regarding the Device Detection but now we have checked, it seems to be working fine.

So any idea about this issue?

Comment: `XdbCollectionUnavailableException` is thrown when your application cannot connect to xConnect or when xConnect certificate is not valid. Maybe certificate expired? Or xConnect has some issues?

Comment: Most likely your certificate has expired or some network rules have been updated which dont allow your application to connect to xConnect.

Comment: There is a similar one at https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24977/error-with-custom-page-event-model-sitecore-xconnect-schema-xdbmodelexception. Hope it help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the followings-

1. Your certificate is both valid and accessible to the xConnect application.
2. Solr is error-free.
3. Kindly verify that you have created and deployed the custom model in accordance with the recommended link below -
   https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/deploy-a-custom-model.html
4. Ensure that the custom model has been deployed under the Index Manager job within xConnect, and remember to restart the job afterward.